# How to get nearest DNS server throw CloudFlare?

Tags: domain-name-system, cloudflare

My website is hosted in Vietnam, I can see tons of servers which CloudFlare (CF) support in Asia such as Hangzhou, China, Hanoi, Vietnam, Hengyang, China, Ho Chi Minh City, Vietnam…

But when I send PING test to my website, the response IP always in USA, and response time kind of high, not stable (~300ms). Slow when access website too, I switch all of my ISP in my country to test, result always high ping.

[image]

I have searched everywhere and not found the way to use Asia cloud server instead of USA to prevent slow speed of my website. I am now using gail.ns.cloudflare.com, matt.ns.cloudflare.com DNS name for my domain.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the name server you have configured in your MacBook? Because when you for instance use something like opendns or a VPN connection that overrides your ISP provided name servers anything that  relies on anycast DNS will use the approximate location of that nameserver, rather than the location of your ISP, to direct you to a nearby edge server.

Comment: We'd have to check your DNS setup to see what's up. It could be your connection, your DNS, or something wrong with your test.